# Sorting a DataSource does not sort the visible list on the screen

Tags: android, android-paging-library, android-listadapter

I have the following extension function -

```kotlin
fun DataSource.Factory<Int, CountryEntity>.sortBy(comparator: Comparator<in CountryEntity>): DataSource.Factory<Int, CountryEntity> {
    return mapByPage { list ->
        list.sortedWith(comparator)
    }
}
```

And the following implementation -

```kotlin
class CountriesRepository(val viewmodel: ViewModel) {
.
.
.
    fun getAllCountries(comparator: Comparator<in CountryEntity>?): LiveData<PagedList<CountryEntity>> {
        if (comparator == null)
            return countryDao.getAllCountries().toLiveData(10)
        return countryDao.getAllCountries().sortBy(comparator).toLiveData(10)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
//Fragment 
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        var comparator: Comparator<CountryEntity>? = null
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.country_list_menu_order_by_country_name_ascending -> {
                comparator = compareBy { country -> country.nativeName }

            }

            R.id.country_list_menu_order_by_country_name_descending -> {
                comparator = compareByDescending { country -> country.nativeName }
            }

            R.id.country_list_menu_order_by_area_ascending -> {
                comparator = compareBy { country -> country.area }
            }

            R.id.country_list_menu_order_by_area_descending -> {
                comparator = compareByDescending { country -> country.area }
            }
        }
        countriesViewModel.getAllCountries(comparator).observe(this, Observer { list ->
            countriesAdapter.submitList(list)
        })
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

The issue I am facing is the fact that the list does indeed get sorted but the visible portion of the list does not, meaning I need to scroll down in order for the list to invaidate itself and than scroll back up to see the updated data.

Also, it seems like it always ignored the first item in the list and does not show it

What am I missing? 
Another thing - how do I get rid of the animations of ListAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

If your RecyclerView or ListView contains only countries, then you should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh changed dataset.

Clear the RecyclerView item animator to remove item animation.

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

You can re-enable your animation after if needed.

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Comment: about the animation thanks it works but calling `notifyDataSetChanged` did not help, also isn't redudant to call `notifyDataSetChanged` when working with ListAdapter?